# Adjusting margins for R plots

Tags: r, plot, margin

I'm interesting in adjusting margins for R plots. I use R Studio on MacOS, run on a 2013 intel CPU Macbook pro.

Here is the data I used for generating the plot:

```
spins <- runif(50, min = 0, max = 50)
```

Here is the code I used to generate the plot:

```
hist(spins)
```

Here is the results of the console:

```
> hist(spins)
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Here are my questions:

1. How do I find out the current margins of this specific plot?
2. How do I modify the margins for this specific plot?
3. Is there a method to modify the margins for plots in general (e..g., Can I use 1 set of code to find the margins of the object and then use a second set of code to modify the margins so it will display in the plots area)?
4. Is there code I can use to automatically adjust the margins of the plots so that the desired plot displays every time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `par` function can be used to see the size of current margins and to set margin sizes (plus a whole bunch of other things).

Running `par(c("mar", "mai"))` will report the current margins (starting at bottom and going clockwise) in lines of text (`mar`) and inches (`mai`).

You can then set the margins using code like: `par(mar=c(2,2,2,0))` or `par(mai=rep(0.4, 4))`.

But the problem is probably that you have made the plots pane in RStudio too small in at least one dimension, so when the `hist` function tries to create the plot there is not enough room for the plot and margin information.  Try dragging the appropriate dividers within RStudio to make the plot panel larger then try your code again.  Another option is to run the command `dev.new()` which will open a new window for the plots (using the default for your OS) and by default send the plot to that new window instead of the plot pane in RStudio.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I got it to work using your suggested code.
I do have 1 question. Is there a way to use code to figure out what current margins are for the  `hist(spins)` object?

Comment: @Mel, The `par` function will tell you the current settings.  Base plot functions like `hist` will use those settings.  The 'par("plt")` results may be of help as well.  Also, see the help for `grconvertX` for a way to convert from the `par("plt")` results to what may be more meaningful to you.